# Trying to populate string with values from object properties - getting "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve the below Javascript kata on Codewars but getting "undefined". Can please someone show me the light on what exactly is "undefined". I am struggling to understand what is missing form my code below. Cheers.

Link to challange: https://www.codewars.com/kata/training-js-number-5-basic-data-types-object

I've searched through FreeCodeCamp JS OOP and Basic tutorials / lessons to find similar problems.  Searched through StackOverflow, Reddit, and Googled many websites for similar challanges.
Code below:

```
function animal(name, legs, color) {
  this.name = name;
  this.legs = legs;
  this.color = color;
}
var dog = new animal("dog", 4, "white");
// similar variables set such for other animal objects.
animal.prototype.toString = function animalToString() {
  var sent = "This " + this.color + " " + this.name + " has " + this.legs + " legs.";
  return sent;
}
return animal.prototype.toString.call();
```

Expected: `This white dog has 4 legs.`, instead got: `undefined`

Comment: I think you are calling it wrong. Try `dog.toString()`

Comment: I tried that before but the codewars test still returns the same 'undefined' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function animal(obj){
  var newAnimal = {
    name: obj.name,
    legs: obj.legs,
    color: obj.color
  };


return "This " + newAnimal.color + " " + newAnimal.name + " has " + newAnimal.legs + " legs.";
}
```

The purpose of this kata I believe is to introduce you to javascript objects. The issue is thrown when you changed the inputs of the function "animal". If you look at the sample tests in the lower right corner, the inputs being fed into the function you are trying to make should accept only one parameter which is an object with properties name, legs, and color. You changed this input into three separate parameters instead of just one.

Or you could skip the assignment altogether and just access the input directly like so:

```
function animal(obj){

return "This " + obj.color + " " + obj.name + " has " + obj.legs + " legs.";
}
```

Comment: Pete - this works! Thank you so much for the help and insight.  I didn't realise that it was this simple.  I totally over-complicated it with my attempt.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

1) Based on 'instructions'

Give you a function animal, accept 1 parameter obj like this: {name:"dog",legs:4,color:"white"} and return a string like this: "This white dog has 4 legs."

```
function animal({name, legs, color}) {
    return `The ${color} ${name} has ${legs} legs.`;
}
```

2) Based on what you're supposed to learn

```
function animal({name, legs, color}) {
  this.name = name;
  this.legs = legs;
  this.color = color;
}

animal.prototype.toString = function animalToString() {
  return `The ${this.color} ${this.name} has ${this.legs} legs.`;
}

var dog = new animal({name:"dog", legs:4, color:"white"});
dog.toString();
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the quick reply.  I've amended my code to reflect similar changes to yours and also tried copying and pasting your code with the template literals.  However, the codewars test still throws the 'undefined' error...

Comment: Don't waste your time on games like that, not capable of giving clear feedbacks. Read real project code or books about JS/dev/..., build a projet by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function animal(obj){
     return `This ${obj.color} ${obj.name} has ${obj.legs} legs.` 
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
function animal(obj){
  var a={name:"dog",legs:4,color:"white"}
  return "This" + " " + a.color + " " +a.name + " " + "has" + " " + a.legs + " " + "legs.";
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to break the spaces out from the rest of the text.

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)